# Unexpected Response from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token. Not giving "access_token", only "id_token"

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm trying to get an access token so I can use the Google Cloud TTS.

This looks the only way I can do it. I'm using Cloudflare workers and because this needs to run on a browser, some of libraries that I think would facilitate the job I can't use.

I'm in an internship, the guy who gave me this task sent me this file.

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "...",
  "private_key_id": "...",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMII...NF0=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "...",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "..."
}
```

I already could create an audio using this file by putting the path of the file as an specific environment variable and then using the `gcloud` CLI tool to print the access token, then I used it. But I didn't know the token changed.

Now I'm trying to use JWT tokens.

This is a file that I created to test the JWT.

It creates the JWT but when I do the POST request to get the `access_token` in the Response I just get the `id_token`.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const credentials = require("./credentials.json");

const corsHeaders = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Authorization",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true,
}

async function main() {
  const JWTToken = jwt.sign({
    "iss": credentials.client_email,
    "sub": credentials.client_email,
    "scope": "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1",
    //"aud": credentials.token_uri,
    "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    "exp": Math.floor(+new Date() / 1000) + 60 * 45,
    "iat": Math.floor(+new Date() / 1000),
  }, credentials.private_key, {
    "algorithm": "RS256",
    "header": {
      "kid": credentials.private_key_id,
      "typ": "JWT",
      "alg": "RS256",
    }
  });

  const JWTBody = new URLSearchParams();

  JWTBody.append("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
  JWTBody.append("assertion", JWTToken);
  
  let JWTResponse;
  
  try {
    //JWTResponse = await fetch("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
    JWTResponse = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JWTBody,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return new Response(`${e.name}: ${e.message}`, {
      status: 500,
      statusText: "Internal Server Error",
      headers: new Headers(corsHeaders),
    });
  }
  
  let JWTResponseBody;

  if (JWTResponse.ok) {
    JWTResponseBody = await JWTResponse.json();

    console.log("JWT", JWTResponseBody);
    console.log("JWT ACCESS_TOKEN", JWTResponseBody["access_token"]);
  } else {
    console.error("HTTP status code: ", JWTResponse.status, JWTResponse.statusText, JWTResponse);
  
    return new Response("HTTP status code: " + JWTResponse.status + JWTResponse.statusText, {
      status: 500,
      statusText: "Internal Server Error",
      headers: new Headers(corsHeaders),
    });
  }

  const TTSGoogleAPIsEndpoint = new URL("https://texttospeech.googleapis.com");
  const TTSRESTResources = {
    synthesize: new URL("/v1/text:synthesize", TTSGoogleAPIsEndpoint),
    list: new URL("/v1/voices", TTSGoogleAPIsEndpoint),
  };

  let response;

  try {
    response = await fetch(TTSRESTResources.synthesize, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: new Headers({
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${JWTResponseBody["access_token"]}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "audioConfig": {
          "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16",
          "pitch": 0,
          "speakingRate": 1
        },
        "input": {
          "ssml": "<speak> <emphasis level=\"strong\">To be</emphasis> <break time=\"200ms\"/> or not to be? </speak>"
        },
        "voice": {
          "languageCode": "en-US",
          "name": "en-US-Standard-A"
        }
      }),
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return new Response(`${e.name}: ${e.message}`, {
      status: 500,
      statusText: "Internal Server Error",
      headers: new Headers(corsHeaders),
    });
  }

  if (response.ok) {
    const audio = await response.json();

    console.log(audio);
  } else {
    console.error("HTTP status code: ", response.status, response.statusText);
    console.log(response.headers.get("WWW-Authenticate"));

    return new Response("HTTP status code: " + response.status + response.statusText, {
      status: 500,
      statusText: "Internal Server Error",
      headers: new Headers(corsHeaders),
    });
  }
}

main();
```

When I run the code it prints this:

```
(node:53185) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
JWT {
  id_token: 'eyJh ... THE ID_TOKEN ... BSZw'
}
JWT ACCESS_TOKEN undefined
HTTP status code:  401 Unauthorized
Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="invalid_token"
```

I've console logged the `JWTToken` already and did the POST Request on Postman. It gives the same Response, only the `id_token`.

I think the problem can be the JWT payload content, I don't know if the scope it's right neither if I need to use the `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` URL or the one in the credentials for the `aud`. The same about the URL that I need to use for the `fetch()`. But I think I tested all the URL possibilities and it never gives the `access_token`.

Thank you

---

## Solution

The scope on the JWT payload was wrong. It needs to be `"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",`.

Answered by John Hanley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is specifying an OAuth scope that does not exist (and the format is entirely wrong).

```
async function main() {
  const JWTToken = jwt.sign({
    "iss": credentials.client_email,
    "sub": credentials.client_email,
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    ...
```

The URI `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` is correct. You can also use the value from `auth_uri`: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`.

That should solve the problem with the JWT Access Token. If you have further problems with the Text To Speech API, post a new question.

Comment: Thank you John Hanley. It was the scope :)